# Using Appengine Standard user login service, how to prompt longer login login interval?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

We use provided [user login](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/users/) in App Engine Java Standard environment. "Google login cookie expiration" is set to maximum of 2-weeks.

For a new user, the login screen will prompt with option to "Remember this approval for 30 days".

User opted-out the option, but want to opt-in in next login. But the opt-in option to "Remember this approval for 30 days" no longer show in subsequent login.

Without opt-in, the user was logout automatically every day. Each day, user still need to click the login link, but no username/password prompt. Even if change the login with `passive=false`, the option to "Remember this approval for 30 days" does not show.

Logout and then Login also does not show the option. Adding `prompt=consent` in the login URL also does not show the option.

How to make "Remember this approval for 30 days" for subsequent user?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have reached the quota limit for the non-verified apps in OAuth-Google?

Comment: [It is a verify app](https://www.yathit.com/portal/) and quota limit is not reach.